# foreach loop and json_encode only returns one object Joomla 2.5 Component

Tags: php, jquery, joomla2.5, json

Im currently making a google maps component for Joomla 2.5 using Gmaps3, im at the point where it populates the map with markers, but my foreach loop is only returning one object.

Code below:

My View.json.php:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');

class LocateViewBranches extends JView
{
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $branch = $this->get('Branches');

        foreach ($branch as $row) {
                $response = array(
                        'lat' => $row->branch_latitude,
                        'lng' => $row->branch_longitude,
                        'data' => array(),
                    );
                $response['data'][] = array(
                    'city' => $row->branch_city,
                );

        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

and then in my Model;

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

class LocateModelBranches extends JModel
{
    public function getBranches()
    {
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__branches');
        $query->where("published = 1");

        $db->setQuery($query);

        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

        return $rows;
    }
}
```

Please shout if you guys need more code, but i think those are the two key files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'll need to `array_push` the `$response` onto a new array variable, and `json_encode` that array instead.

Comment: Yeah... youre overwriting `$response` on each iteration of the loop, not adding to it.

Comment: How would you guys go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tidied up your display function. It will echo a multidimensional array in json format:

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $responses = array(); // assign each row to this array

    $branch = $this->get('Branches');
    foreach ($branch as $row) 
    {
        // append row data to $responses array
        $responses[] = array(
            'lat' => $row->branch_latitude,
            'lng' => $row->branch_longitude,
            'data' => array(
                'city' => $row->branch_city
            ),
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($responses);
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should be what you need.